# Is there a way to skip a level with telerik RadGrid in tree mode?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Here's the situation: I've got a two level tree that I'm displaying in a hierarchical RadGrid:

```
-Category 1
--Cat 1 Section 1
--Cat 1 Section 2
-Category 2
--Cat 2 Section 1
--Cat 2 Section 2
--Cat 2 Section 3
-Category 3
--Cat 3 Section 1
```

and so on.  But I was just handed a new requirement that the categories themselves are actually children of another kind of entity:

```
-Bucket 1
--Bucket 1 Category tree...
-Bucket 2
--Bucket 2 Category tree...
```

The part of the requirement that I can't figure out how to express in the RadGrid is this (actually this is simplified from the whole ugly truth): **if** there are multiple buckets in the data set, they want the root level of the tree to be the buckets, but if there is only one bucket, they do **not** want the root to be that single bucket node; rather they just want the root level to be the categories in that lone bucket.

My problem is that I'm not seeing a way to remove that bucket level from the control and promote the next level to the root.  Is there any way to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will all come down to the binding that you create. I don't think there is another way to do it.

```
if (ShowAll)
{
     RadGrid1.DataSource = GetBucketsAll();
} 
else
{
     RadGrid1.DataSource = GetCategoriesByBucketId(id);
}
```

Then work your way thru the GridDetailTableDataBindEvent.

Comment: I don't really see how that helps me.  If !ShowAll, then I get the single bucket, but AFAICT you still get that bucket at the root of the hierarchy.  I need a way to remove it entirely from the tree.

Comment: There must be a relationship between the bucket and the bucket categories, so you just get the categories of the bucket GetCategoriesByBucketId(id); Which in turn will have only categories from a certain bucket. If you using entities it would be something like context.Buckets.Where(d => d.Id = Id).FirstOrDefault().Categories

Comment: I know how to get the categories, I just don't know how to get the RadGrid not to display the MasterTableView that shows the buckets, and instead display the child DetailTables.GridTableView that contains the categories.

Comment: You can't hide the MasterTable that's why I'm telling you that you need to change its Datasource to categories or you can have two Radgrids one for categories and one for the buckets. If you hide the MasterTable you hide everything.

Comment: Okay, now I get what you're saying.  But then the problem is that the master Bucket table has different structure (columns, styles, etc.) than the detail Category table.  So I can easily set the data source for the master table to be either the buckets or the categories (as you showed in your code sample), but what I don't see how to do is to specify that in the one case, the master table consists of bucket structure (with category and section descendents), but in the other case, it consists of category structure with only section descendents.  IOW, how can I dynamically configure the layout?

Comment: You can use the ItemTemplate for that and use the Eval() to get the values of the rows. Here's an example http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/listview/defaultcs.aspx, but it will also depend on what you have created so far.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction enough that I'll accept it as the answer.  To get this to work, in addition to dynamically swapping the data sources, I also wrote code to clear the properties of the master table and reset all the properties to those of the level 2 table, and then added the level 3 table as a child of the (newly reconfigured) level 1 table.  This is kind of kludgy, and I think Telerik needs to have resuable external swappable templates, like Silverlight, to make this kind of thing easier, but I at least I got it to work.  Thanks for all your input.